# Calculate the overlap between two unrelated tables in posgres/posgis

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, postgis, psql

This is both a basic SQL question and a postgres/postgis question.

I have two table sets, in the same database but from different sources, provide similar yet different geographic data.

For instance, the query on first sets

```
select ST_Area(g.geog), g.geog area1 
from 
(--complicated joins on set1 tables---)
order by area1;
```

gives (showing first column only):

```
1449088812.57385
2209542976.77606
2419594400.94064
2680798195.72685
2921972342.3048
2936036972.01677
3420807650.41126
3426766723.91276
4098062224.01722
5082190891.49144
5137325111.41293
5726948701.13547
```

And the query on the second sets:

```
select ST_Area(r.geog), r.geog area2 
from 
(--some other compilcated joins on set2 tables----) 
order by area2;
```

gives (showing first column only):

```
1449087081.39959
2209560820.96132
2419587161.04685
2680790097.03592
2922282361.4318
2936033639.82268
3420802892.77572
3427452706.69087
4098057825.46861
5082187140.27675
5137291729.45781
5726925279.07641
```

They are both 12 rows. I'd like to compare them side by side accordingly. Specifically, I want to calculate the overlap geometry using the 'geog' columns in both query results, possibly using ST_Intersection() or other postgis method. (the area here is just for demonstration purposes.)

How am I supposed to do this? I've tried:
row_number()
WITH ... AS ...
CREATE TEMP TABLE ...
INTO #temp ...

Please point me to the right direction!

Comment: can you compare them using the first few or 3 digits? maybe just a thought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have your full query, but based on the results you gave you could do:

```
WITH CTE1 AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY col1) AS ROWNUM, col1 FROM tab1
),
CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col1) AS ROWNUM, col1 FROM tab2
)
SELECT CTE1.col1 AS RES_T1, CTE2.col1 AS RES_T2
FROM CTE1 FULL JOIN CTE2 ON CTE1.ROWNUM = CTE2.ROWNUM
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d87af/4)</kbd>

Hopefully you can adapt this to your query.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (a.id)
  a.id as a_id,
  b.id as b_id,
  ST_Area(ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom)) as intersect_area
FROM a, b
ORDER BY a.id, ST_Area(ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom)) DESC
```

It will find the best `ST_Area(ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom))` for every row in `a`.